# Not all code paths return a value: if vs switch

Tags: typescript

Why, for the following snippet, the compiler screams at me saying

> Not all code paths return a value

```
const someFunction = (e: "A" | "B") => {
    if (e == "A") return "letter-A";
    if (e == "B") return "letter-B";
}
```

but when using the switch statement it goes back to sleep?

```js
const someFunction = (e: "A" | "B") => {
    switch (e) {
      case "A": return "letter-A"
      case "B": return "letter-B"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there's no mechanism in place to detect a series of `if` statements as being possibly exhaustive the same way there is for a `switch` statement.  There is an open suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#21985](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985) to implement such a feature.  If you want to see it happen, you might want to go there and give it a .

For now the only way to fix this (without refactoring to `switch`) is to either add a dummy `return` or `throw` statement.  If you find yourself doing this often you can write a helper function which only accepts inputs that have been narrowed to `never` due to impossibility, which always `throw`s, and `return` the result of that:

```
const assertNever = (x: never): never => 
  { throw new Error("Oops, unexpected value " + String(x)) };

const someFunction = (e: "A" | "B"): string => {
  if (e == "A") return "letter-A";
  if (e == "B") return "letter-B";
  return assertNever(e);
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhCBTATlAckgbqmBeGACgA8AuGMbVASnMpxXwD4YBvGKACxRAHcKk-AKIoeKQgCIA8iAAOEADQwArpWKykwKEgAmMLHAA2ypDAkwA1DADKUFAEswAcxLVqMAL4BuALAAof1BIWAgQAFskADFVLXtwfCIkcgkAQXMAHzMAIQlaGGgHZ2Y2fxgYewAzRPwCVNyYFCQoZRQwM0Mm7RQAWjTfPzLK6rxanPdG5tb2ztRunP6yiZa2hGQ0TAZCJGp+jyA)